# Star Schema Design - Multiple Sources

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, star-schema

I am planning the design of a star schema for a data warehouse. The data will be loaded from 2 separate staging tables (*Client* and *System*).

The end user will need to be able to compare any differences between the 2 sets of data. They will also need to be able to match items from either source. e.g. ItemA from SourceA matches ItemA from SourceB.

For the design, I am considering having both sources on one row in the Fact Table. So for SourceA (*Client* source), there would be NULL values for SourceB columns (*System* source) and vice versa. The 'Source' column is then used to flag whether the data is *Client* source or *System* source.

[image]

I am thinking it will be easier to do this design especially when we may need to match items. So on a match, the NULLs would be replaced with the matched item's values.

Am I correct with this design or is there a better solution? Thanks!

Schema design:

[image]